# Flash-like Sprites in JavaScript html5

Tags: javascript, html, flash

2d Gamedevelopment in Flash is very easy because of the included sprite classes and their individual mouse listeners.

i know there are thousands of gamelibarys out there ...
but whats the best Framework to get the same options in javascript with html5 canvas??

Comment: Answers to this question will be subjective.  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are familiar with Flash, you should look at [EaselJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS). It uses the same stage and sprite concepts. I've used it with a few games with great success. It's not a "game library" per se, so you won't get built in physics, etc. It's just a very helpful library for accessing the canvas. The same people make some other libraries for handling sound and resource preloading. If you want to see some samples, I have 2 on github [here](https://github.com/azurelogic/). RRZA actually has a stripped down branch for a talk I gave.